# Migration files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Where can I download the rails migration file for  country, state and city table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for [ISO 3166](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166).  The ISO lists are [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists.htm).

The country select is now outside of rails core in order to sidestep political issues (China - Taiwan and so forth) so you'll need a plugin, such as this [one](http://www.restafari.org/localized-country-select.html), to give you the functionality.

I've never heard of a migration that would populate a table with this data.